# Json, Hibernate, Spring boot

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot

Estou tendo 2 situações que deveriam fazer a mesma coisa mas não fazem:

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id",
        scope = A.class)
public class A {

    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public List<B> bItens = new ArrayList<>();

    public A() {
    }

    public A(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<B> getbItens() {
        return bItens;
    }

    public void setbItens(List<B> bItens) {
        this.bItens = bItens;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", bItens=" + bItens + '}';
    }



}


package com.example.demo.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id",
        scope = B.class)
public class B {

    public Integer id;
    public String itemName;
    public A aOwner;

    public B() {
    }

    public B(Integer id, String itemName, A aOwner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.aOwner = aOwner;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public A getaOwner() {
        return aOwner;
    }

    public void setaOwner(A aOwner) {
        this.aOwner = aOwner;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B{" + "id=" + id + ", itemName=" + itemName + ", aOwner=" + aOwner + '}';
    }

}
```

Como vcs podem ver temos 2 classes onde tem o relacionamento oneToMany.
Se eu executar este código não terei problema algum:

```
@Autowired
    private ARepository ar;

@RequestMapping(value = "/teste1", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity teste1() {
        A a = ar.getOne(1);
        a.getbItens().clear();
        ar.save(a);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("");
    }
```

Ou seja ele ira fazer o delete no banco de dados de todos os objetos do tipo B.
Porem se eu fizer este código:

```
@Autowired
        private ARepository ar;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/teste2", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity teste2(@RequestBody A a) {
            a.getbItens().clear();
            ar.save(a);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("");
        }
```

Simplesmente ele ignora o delete e não faz as exclusões necessárias no banco...

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "dasdsadsa",
    "bItens": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "itemName": "sdfdsf",
            "aOwner": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "itemName": "sdfdsf",
            "aOwner": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "itemName": "sdfdsf",
            "aOwner": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "itemName": "sdfdsf",
            "aOwner": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Segue o json q eu envio no método 2

Seguindo a logica do método 2, ele deveria deletar todos os itens da lista de objetos da classe B e depois fazer o save, porem analisando o log do hibernate.. ele faz os selects e simplesmente deduz não tem nada de diferente... e não faz os deletes, porem se eu fizer alguma alteração nos dados como trocar o name da classe A ou o itemName da classe B ele faz os updates

Comment: O problema esta acontecendo por algum problema do Json, mas eu não consigo identificar como contornar este problema... é Como se o hibernate não conseguisse identificar objetos originados pelo json para fazer todas as operações no banco

Comment: Você já fez um println do conteúdo do @RequestBody?

Comment: Porem no que eu conheco sobre o uso do hibernate, se eu simplismente instanciasse um objeto do tipo A passando a id 1 sem preencher nenhum outro dado e salvar, ele deveria fazer um update no cadastro numero 1 e se tivesse algum objeto atrelado a ele ele deveria remover.... porem se eu faco isso apartir de um json, nao funciona

Comment: ja fiz um printf sim, ele fei com todas as informacoes certinhas, na vdd eu tneho mais 1 metodo q eu chamo pra gerar o json.. ele vem com todos os dados de maneira correta, poderia ate postar aqui se for necessario

Comment: Acredito que, no seu segundo método, o objeto não está sendo gerenciado pelo Hibernate.

Comment: Justamente, estou acreditando fielmente que alguma coisa acontece para o hibernate nao estar gerenciando esse objeto gerado pelo json, mas como fazer ele passar a ser gerenciado?

Comment: Você possivelmente não vai escapar de fazer a busca que você faz no método 1 passando o id ou algum outro campo deste objeto que chega via parâmetro e só então deletar o que precisa. Veja se isso cumpre com o que precisa e avise, para eu criar uma resposta.

Comment: então na vdd o que acontece é o seguinte, o usuário entrara no primeiro método e ele ira gerar um arquivo json q sera mandado para ele, ele faz a modificação no json e manda para o segundo método.... porem ele ira cair na mesma situação em q eu estou passando...

Comment: O q eu estou fazendo atualmente é este processo que posteriormente sera usado pelo cliente: uma url passa o json, eu faco as devidas modificações utilizando um sistema para gerenciar claro e mando o json para a outra url que sera o método do teste2, só que ao chegar neste método como o json não esta mais sendo gerenciado pelo hibernate ele não ira saber o q precisa deletar e não fara a exclusão, neste exemplo eu nao mostro minhas regras de negocio, mas o primeiro método recebera uma ID para saber qual cadastro enviar e o segundo método não fara apenas a exclusão da lista